# How to make a function that contains a promise return a value instead of a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

Say, I have a function F1 that will be called in many other function. F1 is meant to return a value VAL that will be used in F2. A promise is needed to retrieve that needed data that will help calculate VAL. Having F1 as a promise would cause a lot of confusion in F2, for F1 is often called inside IF statements and FOR loops. Let me illustrate this scenario:

```
function F1(param1, param2) {
    var VAL = 0;

    promise(param1, param2).then(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Do some calculation here
        }
    });

    return VAL;
}

function F2(x1, x2) {
    var myArray = [],
        someValue = 0;

    if ([conditional expression]) {
        someValue = F1(x1, x2);

        call_some_function();

        myArray.push({
          val: someValue,
          ...
        });
    }

    var x = someValue + y;

    myArray.push({
        id: x,
        ...
    });

    return myArray;
}
```

How do I make sure that F1 returns VAL (integer) so I can use it as a synchronous function?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

Here is how the code looks like:

```
    function myFunc(x, y) {
        return init()
            .then(function() {
                return getData(x, y).then(function(data) {
                    if (data.length == 0) return [];

                    var id, name, 
                        firstPass = true,
                        headIn = 0, 
                        headOut = 0, 
                        currentHead = 0,
                        payWtIn = 0,
                        payWtOut = 0,
                        expectedAdg = 0,
                        weight = 0,
                        results = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (firstPass) {
                            id = data[i].id();
                            name = data[i].name();
                            headIn = data[i].headIn();
                            headOut = data[i].headOut();
                            expectedAdg = data[i].expectedAdg();
                            firstPass = false;
                        }

                        if (id != data[i].id()) {
                            buildFunc();
                            reset();
                        }

                        headIn += data[i].headIn();
                        headOut += data[i].headOut();
                        payWtIn += data[i].payWtIn();
                        payWtOut += data[i].payWtOut();
                    }

                    buildFunc();

                    return results;



                    function buildFunc() {
                        currentHead = headIn - headOut;

                        var headDays = getHeadDays({ locationId: locationId, groupId: groupId, callDate: null });

                        var totalWeight = headIn != 0
                            ? ((((headDays * expectedAdg) + payWtIn) / headIn) * currentHead) + payWtOut
                            : 0;


                        results.push({
                            id: id,
                            name: name,
                            headIn: headIn,
                            headOut: headOut,
                            headDays: headDays,
                            currentHd: currentHead,
                            totalWt: totalWeight
                        });
                    }

                    function reset() {
                        id = data[i].id();
                        name = data[i].name();
                        headIn = data[i].headIn();
                        headOut = data[i].headOut();
                        expectedAdg = data[i].expectedAdg();
                        payWtIn = 0;
                        payWtOut = 0;
                        weight = 0;
                    }
                });
            });
    }

function getHeadDays(params) {
    var VAL = 0;

    promise(params.a, params.b).then(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // Make calculation to determine VAL here                           
        }
    });

    return VAL;
}
```

The `init` function loads needed entities in the cache (I'm working with BreezeJs) for querying. The `getData` function gets raw data that are sorted by id from database, and those data are used to determine the `results` array. As the data are looped through, as long as the `id` of each record is the same, `headIn`, `headOut`, `payWtIn` and `payWtOut` are incremented by the record fields, and when the previous and current id are different, we can calculate `totalWeight` and push a new record to the results array with the `buildFunc` function. Inside that buildFunc function, we retrieve the `headDays` in order to calculate `totalWeight`. The `getHeadDays` function will be called in many other functions. Please, let me know if you have any questions. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can't take an async operation and make is synchronous.  Instead, you will need to learn how to program with it in asynchronous fashion and promises are a good way to do that.  You will want to return a promise from `F1` so the caller of `F1` can then use `.then()` on the promise to know when the operation has completed and what value it returned.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I was really hoping I wouldn't read any "can't do" messages, but unfortunately I have to face that fact. Sad but so. :( I guess I'm going to have to make drastic changes on the code. Ugrr!

Comment: So how do I use promises within FOR loops? Any ideas with actual examples would be welcome.

Comment: If you show us what you're trying to do in the `for` loop (add code to your question or start a new question), we can advise.   "Using a promise in a `for` loop" is too generic a question with many possible meanings and solutions.

Comment: @jfriend00: I got a preview of the code on the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

If you *need* to return a promise, then that is because the value won't be available until some event happens, and the function will (or at least may) return before then. That's the point of promises.

Comment: And of course, you have to account for broken promises too... *sigh*

Comment: Yes, I have been using synchronous functions (promises) for quite some time. I just hoped there could be a way of working this situation out. Unfortunately, that cannot happen...

Comment: @RipHamilton you can make it **look** async with ES6 generators if you can use regenerator or a similar project in your build step (or only target chrome or firefox or node).